# Working with multiple remotes in git: "Your branch is ahead of "origin/master" by X commits.."

Tags: git, version-control, git-remote

We have a project with two developers where we have one remote repository that we have both cloned locally and where we push our work.

After pushing changes, we go to another server (let´s call it S), where the actual magic happens ie. production. Here we have to pull the changes of course from the previously mentioned repo.

For reasons we have different remote repos (alt for me and origin for my friend) so when I want my remote changes to update in production I use `git pull alt master` there is a notice that states:

`"Your branch is ahead of "origin/master" by X commits. Use "git push" to publish your local commits."`

What does this mean? Isn´t the actual advice that my friend needs to use 'git pull origin master' in order to update it? I have no writing permissions to origin/master so doesn´t that mean that him making `git pull origin master`in S would make the notice go away?

I understand that this is pretty basic stuff, but we are both pretty new at this stuff so any help is greatly appreciated! :) I also browsed through most of the similar kind of questions, but couldn´t find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> when I want my remote changes to update in production I use `git pull alt master`

but this is not the appropriate action to send your new changes to the production server.

You'd have to `push` your new commits there, this is what the message hints at. "Being ahead" means having commits unknown to the other end.

At the end of the day, once you and your friend agree on a release state, one of you should push the new commits* to your server S.

* *(maybe also consider at this point putting a tag on the commit for this release, this is a good practice to enforce)*

Comment: Thank you for the advice @RomainValeri ! I admit our way of doing this is a bit unorthodox (bad) for now. But the reason we have these steps is because lack of GUI using git, lack of knowledge and since we are both working remotely. Pulling changes to update the server S after going through code locally we found to be more convenient and in this case more efficient than creating merge requests etc.

Answer (score 0):

Lets me explain in steps

1. You have **Remote** branch lets say at some **Commit1**.
2. You cloned the repository and calling your repository as **Alt** and at **Commit1** as Remote Repo.
3. Now you made changes to your Alt and Commited those changes as **X Commits** so current Repo Alt is at **CommitX**.
4. Since there was no one else pushing changes to your **Remote** Repo so your Remote was at commit1 and got never got updated

**"Your branch is ahead of "origin/master" by X commits. Use "git push" to publish your local commits."**

So now why are you getting this message?

because your Remote repo was at **Commit1** and with zero updated changes and current repo is at **CommitX** when you try pulling from your Remote it is basically saying that you have no changes to pull but current repo is ahead by X commit because you made those and not pushed yet, it is suggesting try pushing instead of pull since there are no changes to Pull from remote

To avoid this message Just Push your changes to Remote repo either by direct push using Git Push Commond or you can follow whichever GitFlow you are currently following in your Project